# How do you use a method that takes a function as parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

```scala
val list = List.range(0, 10)

def filter (lst: List[Int], fn: (Int) => Boolean): List[Int] = {
  var res:List[Int] = Nil
  lst.foreach ((x:Int) => if (fn(x)) res = x::res)
  return res.reverse
}
```

The method `filter` takes 2 arguments, first is a list and second is a function which produce a boolean argument.

I want to use this method to get only the even numbers from `list`.

Comment: You cannot *use* this function. The `filter` function does not define a function. Its signature says that it *expects* a function - you have to create such a function yourself (e.g. using a lambda), and *provide* it to `filter`. So your job is to write a function `def isEven (x: Int): Boolean = ???`.

Comment: Yes - use a lambda and/or implement a `FunctionalInterface`.

Comment: Side note: your `filter` method can be rewritten at several levels and is actually even part of the standard library but I assume it's only code to play with the language. You should remove the `return` though. The `reverse` can be avoided. The `var` can also be avoided...

Comment: @PaulieWalnuts `return` is not only unnecessary, [but discouraged](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html). About the other recommendations, there is really no point in learning **Scala** to write imperative code, you can implement that `filter` using a [tail-recursive method](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Rc7eHGYASq6eQyIHZNRFog). - `reverse` is necessary tho, unless you want a cuadracti solution.

Comment: @PaulieWalnuts https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just needs a simple lambda function:

```
filter(list, _ % 2 == 0)
```

This is equivalent to

```
filter(list, x => x % 2 == 0)
```

or

```
def isEven(x: Int) = x % 2 == 0

filter(list, isEven)
```